Laplace transformation of double exponential involving a Poisson process
This is from a series of problems I am working on for self study:
Let us denote by $N(t)$, $t \geq 0$ a Poisson process with $N(0) = 0$ and parameter $\lambda$. Denote by $S_k$ its $k$-th jump time, that is, $N(S_k) = k$, and $S_k - S_{k-1}$, $k \geq 1$ are independent, identically distributed exponential random variables with parameter $\lambda$ for every $k \geq 1$ with $S_0 = 0$. Additionally we denote a quantity $X_t := \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-S_k} \cdot 1_{\{S_k \leq t\}}$ for every $t \geq 0$.
Calculate the Laplace transform
$$
\varphi_t(\theta) := \mathbb{E}\left[\exp\left(-\theta X_t\right)\right], \quad \theta > 0, t \geq 0
$$
of $X_t$ for every $t \geq 0$ and then calculate the Laplace transform of the limiting distribution of $X_t$ as $t \to \infty$.
Hint: Recall how to simulate the Poisson process on the fixed time interval $[0, t]$, that is, given the condition $N(t) = k$, the joint distribution of $S_1, \dots, S_k$ is that of the order statistics of $k$ independent, uniform random variables $U_i$ on $[0, t]$, i.e., we may rewrite $S_j = U_{(j)}$ for $j = 1, \dots, k$, where the i.i.d. uniform random variables $U_i$, $i = 1, \dots, k$ on $[0, t]$ are ordered with $U_{(1)} < \dots < U_{(k)}$.
Note: We also have the following equality (though I'm not sure it makes things simpler):
$$
N(t) \cdot e^{-t} + \int_0^t e^{-u} N(u) \, du = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-S_k} \cdot 1_{\{S_k \leq t\}}, \quad t \geq 0
$$

I have so far found the following since $S_k \leq t$ effectively makes the series bound $N(t)$:
$$
E[e^{-\theta X_t}] = E[\exp(-\theta \sum_{k=1}^{N(t)} e^{-S_k})]
$$
We can then apply the tower property and calculate the following (skipping some simplification since it's nasty to write):
$$
E[E[\exp(-\theta \sum_{k=1}^{N(t)} e^{-S_k}) | N(t) = n]] = E\left[\prod_{k=1}^n \exp(-\theta e^{-S_k})\right]
$$
At which point I get stuck since that is a disgusting looking expectation to calculate. I haven't even attempted the limiting distribution yet (which hopefully is simpler since the limiting value of $X_t$ should just be $X:= \sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-S_k}$).
